# how to implement nested listmodels in qml

Tags: qt, qml, listmodel

Is it possible to implement 3 `ListModels` (one inside the other) and if yes how could I do it?
The 3 `ListModel`s are for hour day and month accordingly.In other words I want one model for hour inside the model for day inside the model for month and  I am going to use them in nested `ListView` s (3 of them ) to display the hour the day and the month in a calendar. I have made a try below :

```
   ListModel{
      id:monthlistModel
      ListElement {
                  monthName:0
                  daylistModel:[
                      ListElement  {
                          day:0
                          hourlistModel: [
                            ListElement{ hour:0;notes:"" }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
       }
        ListElement {
                  monthName:1
                  daylistModel:[
                      ListElement  {
                          day:1
                          hourlistModel: [
                            ListElement{ hour:1;notes:"" }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
       }
```

but I could not finish it .
Moreover I have some typeerror issues when I am running my code.The `hourlistModel`  insists to be undefined for my nested listview and I dont no why.
Anyway back to my question , how can I go on with the above  `listmodel` to display 24 hours , 31 days and 12 months ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest doing this imperatively with javascript rather than declaratively in QML, as it can be more dynamic and brief. One downside is that this is not well documented in my experience.

If you append an array to a ListModel, all of the array elements are converted into ListElements. Further than this, if an array is appended, and that array has nested arrays inside of it, the nested arrays are automatically converted to nested ListModels inside.

Here is a full example:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 600

    ListModel {
        id: monthsModel

        Component.onCompleted: {
            let months = [
                    {
                        name: "January",
                        days: createDays(31) // returns an array, nested arrays become nested ListModels when appended
                    },
                    {
                        name: "February",
                        days: createDays(28)
                    },
                    // add more months etc.
                ]
            append(months) // appending a whole array makes each index into a ListElement at the top level
        }

        function createDays(dayCount) {
            let days = []

            for (let i = 0; i < dayCount; i++) {
                days.push({
                              day: i + 1,
                              hours: createHours()
                          }
                          )
            }
            return days
        }

        function createHours() {
            let hours = []
            for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                hours.push({
                               hour: i,
                               notes: ""
                           }
                           )
            }
            return hours
        }
    }

    // Visual example code starts here ///////////////

    ColumnLayout {
        id: monthsColumn

        Repeater {
            model: monthsModel

            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: month
                color: "pink"
                implicitWidth: daysRow.implicitWidth + 10
                implicitHeight: daysRow.implicitHeight + 10

                RowLayout {
                    id: daysRow
                    anchors {
                        centerIn: parent
                    }

                    Text {
                        text: model.name
                    }

                    Repeater {
                        model: days // refers to the "days" entry in monthsModel.get(<monthIndex>)

                        delegate: Rectangle {
                            id: day
                            color: "orange"
                            implicitWidth: hoursColumn.implicitWidth + 10
                            implicitHeight: hoursColumn.implicitHeight + 10

                            ColumnLayout {
                                id: hoursColumn
                                anchors {
                                    centerIn: parent
                                }

                                Text {
                                    text: model.day
                                }

                                Repeater {
                                    model: hours // refers to the "hours" entry in monthsModel.get(<monthIndex>).get(<dayIndex>)

                                    delegate: Rectangle {
                                        id: hour
                                        color: "yellow"
                                        implicitHeight: 5
                                        implicitWidth: 5

                                        // do something here with model.notes for each hour
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this shows months in pink, days in orange, and hours in yellow:

[image: months in pink, days in orange, and hours in yellow]

Comment: @fallerdThis is an amazing answer.Thank you very much.Just a question about `days` model.How can I use this model `days` to another `ListView` outside repeaters ?What is the syntax  to refer to this model in another outside this code listview as a model?

Comment: @cgiannakidis After creating/filling the base `monthsModel`, you can reach into this model to get and use any of the nested `days` models (there is 1 `days` model per month) by doing something like `monthsModel.get(<your month index here>).days`. So to get the `days` model for the first month: `monthsModel.get(0).days`.

Comment: @fallerdOK.And if I want to access `notes` in `hours` model for updating the text of `notes` how I must express it , what is the syntax for that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cgiannakidis Since these are also nested, they are accessible in the same manner, just deeper. For example, the first day of the first month's `hours` model is accessible with `monthsModel.get(0).days.get(0).hours`. And similarly, the `notes` for the first hour of that day is: `monthsModel.get(0).days.get(0).hours.get(0).notes`. In my example, though, `notes` is a string and not a model, but it could be made into a model by making it an array instead of empty string in `createHours()`

Comment: @fallerdOK.This is for a certain hour a certain day a certain month.Can I use `monthsModel.get(currentIndex).days.get(currentIndex).hours.get(currentIndex).notes` for a moment I choose through `MouseArea` in `ListView`?

Comment: @cgiannakidis Depends. Your code frag is re-using the same `currentIndex` rather than the `currentIndex` of the appropriate ListViews. I would think you would need something more like `monthsModel.get(monthListView.currentIndex).days.get(dayListView.currentIndex).hours.get(hourListView.currentIndex).notes`. As with everything, this sort of depends on the scope you want to call this from, there may be a simpler answer. If you are inside my yellow "hour" delegate, as commented there, you can just refer to notes there with `model.notes`

Comment: @fallerdOK.I have implemented the above code using the currentIndex of the appropriate ListViews but I keep getting type errors.Could you please take a look in my code in the link below? I would appreciate it very much  https://gist.github.com/cgiannakidis70/a5f0f73440013424fc0dedd7e3300f75

Comment: @cgiannakidis Looks like the scoping problem I mentioned before. You cannot resolve your inner ListViews (and their currentIndex) from that scope. I am not clear on what you are attempting to do, so I don't really have a recommendation at this point.

Comment: @fallerdin simple words what  I am trying to do is to set in a text field a"note" , then set this  "note" to `Listimodel` role "notes" and after that save the "notes" with `settings` so I can restore it when I reopen the app.I mean that the app is a calendar  and I want to set and save notes in certain  time and day I choose in the app.