# I have 4 nested ListViews where the outer one does not change view, while the currentIndex is changed QML

Tags: listview, qml, kde-plasma

Following the answer in the link [how to implement nested listmodels in qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517564/how-to-implement-nested-listmodels-in-qml)  I have managed to make nested listviews with nested listmodels.
The project is a calendar and is consisting of 4 listviews, "year", "month", "day" and "hour".These listviews are connected with a `Calendar{}` so  I can get selected `Date()` and display it in the listviews.The problem is that the "day" and "month" are changing accordingly the selected `Date()` but "year" stays freezed.

Full code is in below link https://gist.github.com/cgiannakidis70/b95cfcf21376b5896967d9a00d8d3dbf

How can I make "year" listview  change view accordingly with the others  when i change the selected `Date()` in `Calendar{}`.
Any help will be  appreciated because I am stucked with it for days and I can not find the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `currentIndex` of year `ListView`.I had to express it like this: `currentIndex:calendarMonth.selectedDate.getFullYear()-2022` .Now the `ListView`'s are working perfectly.